# Kill Process When Another Opens

Tags: process, autohotkey

I've tried some variations of this without luck:

```
Process, Exist, Game.exe
    Process, Close, GamePatcher.exe
Return
```

I'm playing a game where the launcher/patcher stays open even after the game launches.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A While loop should help you out.  Here is a solution using a little `ProcExists` function that can be reused.

```
Loop
{
    If ProcExists("Game.exe") and ProcExists("GamePatcher.exe") 
        break
    Sleep 500
}
; Both procs exist, wait for Game to close.
While ProcExists("Game.exe")
    Sleep 500
Process, Close, GamePatcher.exe
Reload ; Reloads waiting for both to exist again

ProcExists(p)
{    
    Process, Exist, % p
    Return ErrorLevel
}
```

If you want this to perform continuously (keep the script running at all times), it would be best to implement `SetTimer` like this:

```
#Persistent

SetTimer, checkGame, 1000
Return

CheckGame:
If ! ProcExists("Game.exe")
    Process, Close, GamePatcher.exe

ProcExists(p)
{    
    Process, Exist, % p
    Return ErrorLevel
}
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid the timer because I already have another one running.  The first example doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: The way it is written, the script must be started after the Game already exists.  Is that the case? I can edit the script to wait for the Game to exist first.

Comment: "GamePatcher.exe" has a button in it (PLAY) that launches "Game.exe"  So ...I think... the edit you're suggesting would fix this?

Comment: Make sure that it is really game.exe that is running (and you want to interact with) and not another program launched by game.exe.

Comment: It is indeed Game.exe.  When it boils down, all I'm trying to do is close one process when another one opens.  Appreciate the help so far!

Comment: Did you try executing the first script AFTER launching your Game?

Comment: I did not.  Couldn't I just close the patcher manually at that point?  If I'm not mistaken that would defeat the purpose of this script :\

Comment: That was for troubleshooting purposes.  I've edited the first script to wait for both the Game.exe and GamePatcher.exe to exist before waiting for Game.exe to close.